# How to finding the line of best fit for a exponential decay set of data points

Tags: linear-algebra, exponential-function, exponentiation, exponential-distribution, chemistry

Im having some trouble trying to find a line of best fit that would go through the values of some values for a chemistry experiment.

Here is the data:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Reaction Time(s)& Concentration (M) \\ \hline
 78 & 0.15\\ \hline
 84  & 0.14\\ \hline
 89  & 0.13\\ \hline
 95 & 0.12\\ \hline
 106  & 0.11\\ \hline
 117  & 0.10\\ \hline
 127  &0.09 \\ \hline
 147   &  0.08\\ \hline
 168  & 0.07\\ \hline
188  &  0.06\\ \hline
 353  & 0.05 \\ \hline
 518  & 0.04\\ \hline
682  & 0.03\\ \hline
\end{array}

[image]
And here is the graph (feel free to ignore the blue line).

Is there any exponential decay function that could go through these to give a $r^2$ value? I tried on my ti-84 plus with no luck

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The simplest way to detect exponential decay is typically to plot the y-axis on a log scale. If $y=ae^{-bx}$, then $\ln y = \ln a-bx$ is linear.

Answer (score 1):

You should check non-linear regression which should be implemented in different software. For fun, I recently coded a script in python that does exaclty what you want. I did run your dataset in it and got the folowing result:

[Exponential](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUgNm.png)

The equation of the exponential is $$ae^{-bx} + h$$ with the value $a = 0.339833797871496$, $b= 0.0146726062591541$ and $h =0.0391506240940973$. The $r^2$ value is $0.989065791920668$.

Comment: If one expects exponential decay to zero, so that $y=ae^{-bx}$, then taking logs of both sides yields $\ln y = \ln a-b x$. So one can do linear regression on $(x,\ln y)$ in that case. (This amounts to doing a best-fit line on the log-plot, as is common.)

Comment: I didn't know you needed $h=0$. Thank's for the clarification! In that case, your method is clearly simpler.

Comment: Well. I'm not the user. And there are cases where you wouldn't expect decay to zero. For instance, suppose you put a hot object in a cold room. Then (per Newton's law of cooling) the temperature difference would relax to zero over time. But the temperature itself would not, and therefore one would need to include $h$.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps heaps! ;)